# Malfunction of 74LS393 4-bit counter

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, counter

I am trying to implement a circuit that will sense a change in capacitance and reflect it in a change of flashing frequency for an LED.

I used [NE555P timer](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf) and a [74LS393](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets/70/375636_DS.pdf) counter. The circuit connection is as shown below:

[image]

RA and RB are in the Mohm range, C2 is 100nF, Csence is in the range of 10-100pF.
The output of the timer is connected to to the counter for frequency division (to make it suitable for the LED). OUT of the 555 timer has frequency of 242.4Hz.

I noticed a malfunction in the counter and I couldn't figure out the reason.
I probed the outputs of the counter using oscilloscope:

Out: 242Hz

Q0: 118.4Hz

Q1:59.7Hz

Q2: 59.5Hz (duty cycle 17%)

Q3:29.77Hz

I don't understand what can cause a wrong output at Q2?

Sceenshots are below:
[image]

Additionally, when cascading the two 4-bit counters in the IC, the second counter output is as follow:

Q0:14.8Hz

Q1:7.4Hz

Q3: Faulty signal

Q3 is shown below:

[image]

EDIT: I found that once I feed the two chips from different channels of the DC source (Different VDD and GND channels, though VDD is 5 V for both), the issue gets resolved.

However, I don't understand the theory behind what happened?

Comment: Are the supplies properly decoupled? I can't remember seeing this unclear tops/spikes with any 74 series counter, but its been a while...

Comment: @PlasmaHH I didn't use any decoupling techniques for the supplies. I just connected all Vcc to a 5V power supply while all GND to the ground of the supply. Will this create a problem?

Comment: @HaneenSu: the LS series is for tens of MHz signals, they are rather fast and gulp up a lot of current. As a rule of thumb, alsways decouple unless you have the confidence to not need it.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I tend to agree, about 20 ms coupled with the "hairs" on the signal.  (Wonder how the traces look in min-max mode?)

Comment: @plasmaHH I tried to feed the counter from a crystal oscillator and it works perfectly fine

Comment: @PlasmaHH Once I used different VDD and GND channels for the two chips from the DC source, the issue was solved. I don't understand however how would this affect the operation of the chip; I mean, I don't quite understand the theory behind that, would you please help me understand this in an answer?

Comment: @HaneenSu: There are many good Q&A here about proper decoupling, they are a better read than any answer I could give.